# Infowindow in Googlemaps wont fill

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got the following problem with Googlemaps.

I've created a createMarker function which returns a marker which I publish with `addOverlay()`. This works perfect, the marker get shown but the only problem is the click event voor the marker, I want a infowindow which is populated with the 'I want this text to be published' text, instead it gets populated with a var called html which I set in the beginning of my code (`var html = 'test';`), I received earlier a message with 'html is not defined', this is why is set the html var. Every infowindow has the text 'test' in it. I've tried using `updateInfoWindow()`  but that doesn't work, anyone familiar with this problem? I can supply you with the full source but I think the createMarker function should be enough.

```
function GM_load() {
   map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
   map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
   map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
   map.enableScrollWheelZoom(); 
   map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);
   geocoder = new GClientGeocoder(); 
   GM_showItems();
}    


function GM_showItems() {
   GDownloadUrl("modules/Googlemaps/ajax/getItems.php", function(data, responseCode) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {


            //start 
            var itemid = markers[i].getAttribute('id');
            var title = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
            var city = markers[i].getAttribute('city');
            var x = 0;
            if (geocoder) {

                geocoder.getLatLng(address + ' ' + city,
                    function(point) {
                        if (!point) {
                            alert(address + ' ' + city + " not found");
                        } else {
                            x = x+1;
                            Marker = createMarker(point, x);
                            map.addOverlay(Marker);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

        }

    });
}




function createMarker(latlng, number) {
    var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
    marker.value = number;
    GEvent.addListener(marker,"click", function() {
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(latlng,'i want this text to be published');
    });

    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I overwrite var html. not perfect but it works.